# Running command prompt from R when running R from command prompt

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am running an R script on the command prompt like this:

`> "R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "myscript.R"`

The code runs fine in RStudio,  but when I run it from command prompt, it stops running after a certain line of code. What's interesting is that the last line that works is a line that itself calls command prompt:

`system("cmd /K my_exe_file")`

That line actually runs successfully, but then the next line doesn't run. There's no error message. Instead, it keeps appearing on command prompt as if the R code is running indefinitely, but in reality nothing is happening.
Is there a problem with calling command prompt when running R from command prompt? Or is there a different issue I'm missing?

Comment: Do you get the same result when switching to `system2` or `shell`? Would it be possible to provide a working example?

Comment: Use `/c` instead of `/k` or simply execute the exe directly without cmd.

Comment: Using `/c` fixed the problem. Thank you.